# Nginx gives localized last-modified headers

Tags: nginx, headers, localization

Nginx gives me localized **last-modified** header. **date** is correct:

```
date: Tue, 07 Dec 2021 17:15:53 GMT
last-modified: So, 20 lis 2021 17:35:33 GMT
```

Is there an option to set correct **en** localization? I suppose it should be always **en** to work correctly.

Comment: Are you getting this from static files or from a webapp?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I had wrong definition for static folder so it was served from webapp. After correct defining static folder in nginx config it started to show correct en header, so nginx is OK.